# Django template fragment caching not working the way it is supposed to

Tags: django, templates, caching, redis, memcached

Referring to following documentation, I am trying this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

```
        {% cache 500 sidebar request.user.username %} 

                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                     {{ user.first_name}} 
{% endif %}
{% endcache %}
```

The problem is my authenticated Name and picture is getting cached and seen by other users, and those of other users by some other user. Essentially anyone coming in hits the cache of previous chap visiting the web site.

Apart from this no user access or any other security issue is not there.

Can you advise why this is so and what is the solution to the problem.

Comment: Do you use the cache middleware or the `cache_page` decorator along with this?

Comment: We are not using cache_page on the view. Yes Cache middleware is set up

Comment: Well that should somewhat answer your question for you, the cache middleware is going to run before even your view (and the cache template tag runs when the template is rendered), i.e. the cached response you get is from the middleware... Try using the `never_cache` decorator.

Comment: The page has almost 300 sql queries. If I use @nevercache page load speeds go up.

Comment: Why are you even using template fragment caching then? It is going to end up cached by the middleware anyway. Use the `vary_on_cookie` decorator to make it vary for each user. Other than that you have 300 queries? Are you sure you can't optimize that? Try looking into `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.